# how can I break the legend into two columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's part of my Python code to plot the legend:

```
plt.legend([hist1,hist2,hist3,expc,expcl,expc2],['$\sigma=2$ (1st scan)','$\sigma=7$ (2nd scan)','$\sigma=12$ (3rd scan)','$\sigma=2$ (expected)','$\sigma=7$ (expected)','$\sigma=12$ (expected)'])
```

And the output looks like

[image]

I wonder how can I move the bottom 3 lines to the right, so that there're 2 columns? I tried to add a `\n` in the middle, but that doesn't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plt.legend([hist1,hist2,hist3,expc,expcl,expc2],['$\sigma=2$ (1st scan)','$\sigma=7$ (2nd scan)','$\sigma=12$ (3rd scan)','$\sigma=2$ (expected)','$\sigma=7$ (expected)','$\sigma=12$ (expected)'], ncol = 2)`

Comment: instead of just showing a long line of code with "you can use", it would be better to **explain** what the difference is. In this case you added a parameter `ncol`. Your answer should mention that. Also a link to a reference would be good.

Comment: @jps Thanks for the advice! In this case, however, the "explanation" seems straightforward so I found no reason to state the obvious. Furthermore, I didn't use any reference.